# Why are anchor tags blue?

Tags: html

Is there a reason blue was chosen for anchor tags or purple was chosen for visited links? Perhaps it has something to do with being easier for people with disabilities?

Comment: http://fagerjord.no/blog/archive/whyareli.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Why are Links Blue?](http://alistapart.com/blog/post/why-are-links-blue)

> Sir Tim Berners-Lee, inventor of the web, is credited with making hyperlinks blue, a decision he appears to have reached at random. But although accessibility may not have been on Sir Tim’s mind at the time, the color choice was a happy one, according to Joe Clark:
>
> *Red and green are the colours most affected by colour-vision deficiency.  Almost no one has a blue deficiency. Accordingly, nearly everyone can see blue, or, more accurately, almost everyone can distinguish blue as a colour different from others. It was pure good luck that the default colour of hyperlinks is blue with underlining.*
>
> -Joe Clark, Building Accessible Websites

Comment: That's really interesting. It makes sense.